# Is there a way to have your regex expression do a negative lookbehind to an exception list?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match a certain certain pattern, but want to exclude a list of undesireable matches. I tried using a negative lookahead, but the exceptions list does not get excluded.

I used the regex expression:

```
(\d+)\s+((?:\b(?:N|S|E|W)\b)(?:\s+))((?!\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)\b)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-\/]+)+(?:\s+))((?:\b(?:N|S|E|W)\b)(?:,?\s+)?)? (?:\,)?((?:\b(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT)\b)(?:\s+)?)?#?(?:\s+)?([A-Za-z0-9]+)?
```

I would like for this expression to identify a special type of address. The address should not have a suffix (ST, AVE, RD, CT), but should include a pre-directional(N,S,E,W) and a post directional(N,S,E,W).

I tried to use a negative-lookbehind for captured group 3, but get an error because its not a fixed width. The negative-lookahead for captured group 3 only checks the first character following the lookahead.

The address 130 N MAIN W APT 5 should match, but the address 130 N MAIN ST W APT 5 should not match because it has a suffix. Both address are currently matching.

I would like to target group 3, and check to see if it ends in one of the suffixes listed and not match if it does.

```
Group 1: 130
Group 2: N
Group 3: MAIN (ST)
Group 4: W
Group 5: APT
Group 6: 5
```

Comment: Lookbehinds have to be fixed-length. So if the exceptions are not all the same length, you can't put them in a lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a lookbehind, you might use a negative lookahead to assert that there is no occurrence of any of `(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)` that is followed by either `N` `S` `E` `W` that by itself is followed by one of `(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT)`.

```
(\d+)\s+([NSEW])(?!\s.*?\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)\s+[NSEW]\s(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT))\s+(.*?)\s+([NSEW])\s+(APT|UNIT|#|LOT)\s+(\w+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(\d+)\s+` Capture **group 1,** match 1+ digits and 1+ whitespace chars
- `([NSEW])` Capture **group 2**, match one of `N` `S` `E` `W`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not

  - `\s.*?\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)\s+[NSEW]\s(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT)` Match one of `(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT)\s+` that is preceded by a suffic and a pre-directional
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `(.*?)\s+`Capture **group 3**, match 0+ times any character, as few as possible
- `([NSEW])\s+` Capture **group 4**, match one of `N` `S` `E` `W`
- `(APT|UNIT|#|LOT)\s+` Capture **group 5**, match one of the alternatives
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 6**, match 1+ word chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FQB3iW/1).

If group 5 and 6 should be optional:

```
^(\d+)\s+([NSEW])(?!\s.*?\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)\s+[NSEW]\s(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT))\s+((?:(?!\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)).)*)\s+([NSEW])(?:\s+(APT|UNIT|#|LOT)(?:\s+(\w+))?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYQ0N8/1)

Comment: This makes the APT|UNIT|#|LOT required, but it is optional. Capture groups 1-4 are required and capture groups 5 and 6 are optional. 130 N MAIN W should also pass, but 130 N MAIN ST W should fail.

Comment: @LynetteGranda Do you mean like this? `^(\d+)\s+([NSEW])(?!\s.*?\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)\s+[NSEW]\s(?:APT|UNIT|#|LOT))\s+((?:(?!\b(?:ST|AVE|RD|CT)).)*)\s+([NSEW])(?:\s+(APT|UNIT|#|LOT)\s+(\w+))?$` See https://regex101.com/r/Y87ox3/1

Comment: Yes. That is it. So the key is doing the negative look-ahead for each relevant capture group.

Comment: @LynetteGranda The part here that allows having an optional group 5 and 6 is that the value in group 3 can not be a suffix using a negative lookahead. In this case it only matches a single character if it is not directly followed by a suffix.

Comment: @LynetteGranda I have updated the answer with the pattern that makes group 5 and group 6 optional.